# "The Children of Captain Grant" tours that follow the book?

Tags: adventure, tours, around-the-world

I was reviewing the book ["The Children of Captain Grant"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Children_of_Captain_Grant) a little while ago and was wondering if there are any tours/adventures that follow the book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer - as best as I can find: No.  However this doesn't mean there won't be.  Historically book tours that exist have tended to only appear once a movie exists.  While Harry Potter existed in book form, platform 9 and 3/4 at Kings Cross only appeared after movies featured it, and Lord of the Rings tours in New Zealand obviously only appeared to show filming locations (as obviously there's no real middle earth to tour).

The best option aside from doing your own might be (if you had the cash) to approach a custom tour company in the regions and ask them to create one for you.